# Express 4- How to set a additional custom cookie with Session?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

From reading [Express 4 Session Documention](https://github.com/expressjs/session)

It states:

> the cookie-parser middleware no longer needs to be used for this
>   module to work. This module now directly reads and writes cookies on
>   req/res. Using cookie-parser may result in issues if the secret is not
>   the same between this module and cookie-parser.

If I want to set a additional custom cookie, such as `loggedIn: true`, how would I do that with Session? I don't see any apis to set cookies other than the default one it makes for it's session tracking. And as the docs state, I should not use `cookie-parser` with `express-session`.

Answer (score 2):

Found out through express.js github:

> The documentation does in no way say you cannot use the two together.
>   It just state that using cookie-parser is not actually required to use
>   this module now (it used to be required in older 1.x versions) and
>   that just keep in mind you have to use the same secret for this module
>   and cookie-parser if you use the cookie-parser module.

Answer (score 0):

> To store or access session data, simply use the request property req.session, which is (generally) serialized as JSON by the store, so nested objects are typically fine. [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session#reqsession)

As it says, you can directly write to req.session

```
req.session.loggedIn = true
```

Comment: No, I need to set a cookie.... an additional cookie to the one session already sets when created. But I can not use cookie-parser with express-session.